# How to make users system example.com/username

Tags: php

How to make users system `example.com/username`

Comment: I recommend you to use a path prefix like `/user/…` to avoid conflicts with other existing URLs like e.g. `/register`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use mod_rewrite if you are on Apache

Here is an article on how you would implement it:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting

Comment: howi can make it ? like that?

Answer (score 1):

This answers your question
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting

Edit: Arg Beaten by 2 minutes. I am slow. oh well here is another link for an alternative method http://www.thyphp.com/friendly-url-without-mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Your web server needs to know how to handle such URLs. Most web server software has an extension that allows to rewrite requested URLs internally.

As for Apache’s web server there is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that allows a rule based URL rewriting. In you case you could use the following rule in the .htaccess file to rewrite such requested URL paths internally to a *user.php* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ user.php [L]
```

Note that this rule does only add a new way to request `/user.php`; so it is still possible the request `/user.php` directly.

Within the *user.php* you can access the requested URI path with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. To extract the user name, you could use the following:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$username = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], 1);
```

Now you just need to adjust your application to serve the proper URLs as mod_rewrite can only rewrite incoming requests and not outgoing responses.

But apart from that, I would rather suggest a different URI design with a distinct prefix like `/user/…`. Otherwise users might choose URLs that conflict with existing ones like `/index.html`, `/robots.txt`, `/sitemap.xml`, etc.